# Caching of sub site menus

Tags: navigation, caching

**Preamble**

We currently have a Drupal 8 site that has subsites (accessed via subdomains).

On the main site (non-subdomain) we have a main navigation menu defined (this is presenting correctly on the main site).

On each sub site we have a domain specific main navigation menu defined (these are presenting correctly on each subsite).

We have a footer menu that is used as a placeholder, defining only top level navigation items (no children). This footer menu is used both on the main site and each sub site.

The footer navigation child items are cloned from the main navigation (if on the main site, the child links are cloned from the main navigation as defined, if on a sub site, the child items are cloned from the sub site main navigation as defined). This is working.

We also do some clean up to remove top level footer items that arent present in the main/sub sites navigation menu.

**Problem**

If we clear the cache & load the main site, we get the expected footer items shown.

If we clear the cache & load a sub site, we get the expected footer items shown.

If we clear the cache & load the main site, and then load a sub site without clearing the cache again, we get the main sites footer items presented, not the desired sub sites footer items.

We have put in place caching directives for `url.site` which we believe should be recognising that the sub site and main site have different url's and should be caching these footer menu's separately.

**Code**

```
// Implements hook_rebuild().

function modulename_rebuild() {
  Menu::load('main')->addCacheContexts(['url.site']);
  Menu::load('footer')->addCacheContexts(['url.site']);
}

// Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter().

function modulename_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name, &$cacheability) {
  $cacheability->addCacheContexts(['url.site']);
}

// Implements hook_menu_links_discovered_alter().

function modulename_menu_links_discovered_alter(&$links) {
  $subdomain = CustomDomainModule::getSubdomain();
  $menu_name = 'main';

  if (!empty($subdomain)) {
    $menu_name = 'main_navigation_' . $subdomain;
  }

  $parameters = \Drupal::menuTree()->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);
  $parameters->setMinDepth(0)->setMaxDepth(2)->onlyEnabledLinks();

  $navMenuItems = \Drupal::menuTree()->load($menu_name, $parameters);

  // Get all top level links for the footer menu.
  $parameters->setMaxDepth(1);
  $footerMenuItems = \Drupal::menuTree()->load('footer', $parameters);
  $count = 0;

  // Enumerate links for the footer menu.
  foreach ($footerMenuItems as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($navMenuItems as $item) {
      // if we have found the matching parent
      if ($item->link->getTitle() === $value->link->getTitle()) {
        if ($item->hasChildren) {
          foreach ($item->subtree as $subItem) {
            $subItemLink = $subItem->link;

            $link = [
              'title' => $subItemLink->getTitle(),
              'description' => $subItemLink->getDescription(),
              'parent' => $key,
              'weight' => $subItemLink->getWeight(),
              'options' => $subItemLink->getOptions(),
            ];

            // Get the route name from the original main nav.
            $originalLink = $subItemLink->getUrlObject();

            if ($originalLink->isRouted()) {
              // Add route properties if there was a route defined on the main nav.
              $link['route_name'] = $originalLink->getRouteName();
              $link['route_parameters'] = $originalLink->getRouteParameters();
            } else {
              $link['url'] = $originalLink->getUri();
            }

            $id = $key . '_alternate_' . $count;
            $links[$id] = $link;

            $count++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The result of hook_menu_links_discovered_alter() is not rebuilt on a normal request, only when modules are installed and in a cache rebuild so that developers can change module code without re-installing.